# SL8051 UART Data is Garbled Every Few Attempts

Tags: 8051

I have about 1500 samples stored in memory from an ADC on a SL8051 development board. When compiling these values into a CSV form to send over UART, the transmission is successful about 3/5 times. The other times it is completely garbled. The baud rate is the same on both sides, and we've checked that the UART sent is consistent with other receiving devices.

Acquisition code

```
 //Code to aqcuire from ADC 
    void main (void)
    {
      // unsigned char delay_count;          // Used to implement a delay
      // bit duty_direction = 0;             // 0 = Decrease; 1 = Increase

       // Disable watchdog timer
       WDTCN = 0xde;
       WDTCN = 0xad;

       PORT_Init ();                       // Initialize crossbar and GPIO

        OSCILLATOR_Init ();
       PCA0_Init ();                       // Initialize PCA0
       EMIF_Init ();                        // Storing ADC samples in SRAM 

       SFRPAGE = CONFIG_PAGE;

       RAM_CS = 0;                          // assert SRAM chip select

       UART0_Init ();                       // initialize UART0

       Timer3_Init (SYSCLK/SAMP_RATE);      // Init Timer3 for 100 ksps sample rate

       ADC0_Init ();                        // configure ADC0 and ADC1 for differential measurement

       EA = 1;                             // Globally enable interrupts


        while(1)
        {                           // loop this logic for multiple samples

           while(BB_GPIO_INPUT == 0);

           SFRPAGE = TIMER01_PAGE;
           TR0 = 1;
           DMA0_Init ();                        // configure DMA to move NUM_SAMP samples

           SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;
           //printf ("Data Acquisition in progress...\n");

           SFRPAGE = DMA0_PAGE;                 // Switch to DMA0 Page

           while (!(DMA0CN & 0x40));            // Wait for DMA to obtain and move ADC samples

           SFRPAGE = LEGACY_PAGE;
           //printf ("Data Acquisition complete.\n");
           SFRPAGE = TIMER01_PAGE;
           TR0 = 0;
           while(BB_GPIO_INPUT == 0);
           SendData();                          // Send data via the UART0

        }
    }
```

UART Code

```
//Code to print the data from DMA   
 void SendData (void)
    {
        unsigned int i;
        char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;
        SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;

        read_ptr = XRAM_START_ADD;   //pointer at beginning of data

        for (i=0; i<NUM_SAMPLES; i++)
        {
            printf("%u",*read_ptr);     // send data as unsigned integers
            putchar(',');
            read_ptr++;
        }
        printf("\n");

        SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;
    }
```

UART Init

```
void UART0_Init (void)
{
    char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;

    SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;           // Switch to UART0 page

    SCON0 = 0x50;                   // SCON: mode 1, 8-bit UART, enable RX
    SSTA0 = 0x10;                   // Timer 1 generates UART0 baud rate and
                                    // UART0 baud rate divided by two disabled

    SFRPAGE = TIMER01_PAGE;         // Switch to timer 0/1 page

//  TMOD = 0x20;                    // TMOD: timer 1, mode 2, 8-bit reload
    TMOD &= 0x0F;                   // clear all T0 control bits
    TMOD |= 0x20;                   // 8-bit auto-reload timer

    TH1 = -(SYSCLK/BAUDRATE/16);    // set timer 1 reload value for baudrate
    TR1 = 1;                        // start timer1;
    CKCON |= 0x10;                  // Timer1 uses SYSCLK as time base
    PCON |= 0x80;                   // SMOD = 1

    SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;           // Switch to UART0 page

    TI0 = 1;                        // indicate TX ready

    SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;          // restore SFRPAGE

}
```

Comment: I'm not going to try to go through the code. Instead, my suggestion would be **simplify, simplify, simplify** :-) Follow a process like [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and produce a *Minimal* set of code which shows the problem. Either you will find the problem during that process, or you will produce a smaller, more focussed test case at the end of it. Also, since you describe the problem as being intermittent, then *something* is changing between when the problem *is* seen, and when it *is not* seen. Try to eliminate variables, aiming to make the problem reproducible every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code actually works. The issue was that the code was processing faster than the UART was being received.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, the problem is almost always due to the receiving system(s) not being able to keep up with the transmitter. Your transmitter is cranking out data at the full baud rate with no interbyte delay and it simply overruns the receiver.

One test you can do is to dramatically lower the baud rate. This gives the receiving system more time to process each received byte. It may not clear the problem completely but if the errors are reduced or occur less frequently you know where to look.

Another test is to place a decent delay between each transmitted character. If the problem goes away, you have found your culprit.